# SQL Server Varbinary to Snowflake Problem

Tags: sql-server, binary, hex, ssms, collation

In SQL Server, the value is `0x005056A0789A1ED88AA08620736740DC`. A process that we cannot get under the hood of is inserting this into Snowflake as varchar `PVáxÜÏèáå sg@▄`.

The value above wrapped in hex_encode makes some sense as the output is `5056C3A178C39C1EC38FC3A8C3A1C3A520736740E29684`. It's a different value but some of the encoded characters are the same.

Any thoughts on what might be going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The varbinary value looks like IBM 850 coding, but indicates that there's a `0x1E` record separator code between `Ü` and `Ï`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was an issue with the tool we were using.